# Printing all numeric data one by one

Tags: bash, grep, pattern-matching

I am provided with text file which contains data (alphanumeric, special characters in any order and layout). Now I have to print all numeric data one by one.

Example :

```
this is txt *24354 filer3243gdt             4332 123
sfdg gtdf, gtdf;tr 3435; gfdsf .43er,       ;43 3543; 
4354w t535 tfgq 3542 fgdg, 243; wre; 24342 ; 24354 ;;;; 13 

tgd dsgf ,3256653756456744rfdgf@gmail.com
```

Output

```
4332
123
3435
43
3543
3542
243
24342
24354
13
```

PS: The problem is there is no specific start or end of these numbers so I am unable to think of RegEx that can do it.

The characters *space*, *comma*, *semi-colon*, *dot*, and *newline* can be used to separate numbers.

Comment: By what rule does a `*` stop `*24354` being a number, but `;` does *not* stop `;43` or `3435;` being a number ?

Comment: I mentioned a note point there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard `tr` and `grep`:

```bsh
tr -s ',;. ' '[\n*]' <file | grep -x '[[:digit:]]*'
```

This first changes all possible delimiting character into newlines (and "squeezes" multiple consecutive newlines into one).  This first step produces the output

```
this
is
txt
*24354
filer3243gdt
4332
123
sfdg
gtdf
gtdf
tr
3435
gfdsf
43er
43
3543
4354w
t535
tfgq
3542
fgdg
243
wre
24342
24354
13
tgd
dsgf
3256653756456744rfdgf@gmail
com
```

From this, `grep` is used to extract  the lines that contains only digits.  The `-x` option to `grep` forces a full line match, and the pattern used matches any number of digits.

The `grep` step results in

```
4332
123
3435
43
3543
3542
243
24342
24354
13
```

This is identical to your expected output.

My first try looked like

```bsh
tr -s '[:punct:][:blank:]' '[\n*]' | grep -x '[[:digit:]]*'
```

which uses *any* punctuation or blank character as delimiter.  This turned out to also get the first `24354` (which in the input is preceded by a `*`).  This may be wrong, but the code *looks nicer* :-)

The `[:punct:]` character class contains the set

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

and `[:blank:]` is space and tab.

Comment: I understood it very well also why your first try got failed as [:punct:] contains * in it so that led to failure but I appreciate your answer thnx a lot

Comment: but I have a doubt imagine you want to count lines where digits occurred so as described by @glenn there I can use `grep -P '(?<=^|\s|;|,)\d+(?=$|\s|;|,)' filename | wc -l` this to get that but in your case how i can do the same

Comment: @solver `tr -s ',;. ' '[\n*]' <file | grep -c -x '[[:digit:]]*'`  The `grep` command knows how to count lines.

Comment: @solver Note that you forgot `-o` when you re-typed glenn's command in your comment.

Comment: No I don;t have to count total number of digits you are getting me wrong instead I have to count total number of lines in that txt file where one or more digits occured `grep -P '(?<=^|\s|;|,)\d+(?=$|\s|;|,)' filename | wc -l` this will work in that case but how to do same in your case

Comment: no I didn't forgot actually when u remove `-o` it will not split all outputs in newline so I can count what I actually want

Comment: I think this: `grep -f <(tr -s ',;. ' '[\n*]' <file | grep -x '[[:digit:]]*') -w file`, but it's not quite right as it matches `*24354` in the first line.

Comment: @glennjackman yes actually for above if we use `wc -l` then we get total lines where occurrence of digits have been occurred thnx for it and btw it don't matches *24354 as he is splitting on the basis of `',;. ' `

Comment: @solver You may want to make this part of the actual question if you want me to incorporate it into my answer.

Comment: that's ok I understood it well here only.

Comment: I have a last query, using this `grep "^[0-9,;\s][0-9]*[0-9,;\s]$" filename` actually start matching the pattern from beggning of line but what if I am interested to do this for matching the pattern anywhere in the whole line becz thats my aim actually to find out all numbers I really request you to guide me as I am happy to know two answers but still if u can modify my approach I will be thankful.

Comment: @solver The `^` and the `$` anchors the pattern to the start and the end of the line. Remove these. This query does not seem to have anything to do with your current question. Consider asking a new question if you have further issues.

Answer (score 0):

PCRE look-arounds are needed here:

```bsh
grep -oP '(?<=^|\s|;)\d+(?=$|\s|;)' file
```

Missing valid separators can be added to the regex in, I think, the obvious places.

Comment: Do u think it will detect the following numbers ?? as in following lines ***line1*** **rrr , 123,**   and ***line2*** **234, 123**

Comment: `grep -oP '(?<=^|\s|;|,)\d+(?=$|\s|;|,)' file` it will work for above cases too, thnx:)

Comment: If I write this `grep "^[0-9,;\s][0-9]*[0-9,;\s]$" filename` can u please tell why this doesn't display the expected result and can you do some modification in it as I don't want to use PCRE

Comment: I know above piece of code works for whole line not in between, I would be grateful to you if I can get some hint

Comment: The PCRE is needed here to match a separator character **but not consume it**. Otherwise "1234,5678" can only match 1234.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -F'[\s,;.]' -lane 'foreach (@F) {print $_ if m/^\d+$/}' inputfile
4332
123
3435
43
3543
3542
243
24342
24354
13
```

This splits each input line into fields, using whitespace and the characters you specified as field separator.

Then, for each field, the script checks if the field contains only digits and prints it if it does.

Comment: Thnx for it now I know four methods to solve my problem :)